# How do I have a value that can be both a floating decimal point or a string in python?

Tags: python, string, if-statement, floating-point, numbers

so, I need one of my variables to be A possibility. like, it is a user input var &  it can be  both a floating decimal point or a string. And, so I want to do stuff with it, like >/</= but if the user says "done" I exit. So, let me show you:

```py
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        float(num)
    except:
        "invalid input"
    if num == "done":
        break
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
        
    if smallest == None:
        smallest= num
        
    if smallest > num:
        smallest = num
    print(num)

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: Just check `if num == "done"` before the `float(num)`.  Note, *you aren't keeping the float you create, you just immediately discard it*. So `num` is still a `str`

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but you can always  perform the `float` conversion after you compare the user input against a string:

```py
largest = float('inf')
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        num = float(num)
    except:
        print("invalid input")
    if num > largest:
        largest = num

    if smallest == None:
        smallest = num

    if smallest > num:
        smallest = num
    print(num)

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Here's a sample play through:

```
Enter a number: 1.2
1.2
Enter a number: 3.4
3.4
Enter a number: 0
0.0
Enter a number: done
Maximum is inf
Minimum is 0.0
```

---

One suggestion for a code simplification I had, assuming you're on Python 3.8+, is to use the walrus `:=` operator, which should allow you to omit the `break` condition:

```py
while (num := input("Enter a number: ")) != 'done':
    try:  # same as before
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, read the number as a string, check if it's "done" and only after convert to a float:

```py
while True:
    num = input()
    if num == "done":
        break
    num = float(num)
    # ... do something with num ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have it for this example. The value you read from user input can be always a string and if this string is not `"done"`, then it should be a float number, otherwise it is invalid. More specifically you don't need your input to be any float or string. You need it to be any float or `"done"`. See the following snippet:

```py
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
  text = input("Enter a number: ")
  if text == "done":
    break
  else:
    try:
      num = float(text)
      if smallest is None or num < smallest:
        smallest = num
      if largest is None or num > largest:
        largest = nunm
    except:
      print("Invalid input")

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```